# Match table with database based on input and return multiple rows - index Match / vlookup?

Tags: google-sheets

I'll try to explain this the best i can.

I've got a database that hardly ever changes on 1 tab and i've got a dynamic table on other tab which is generated with data from the web.

I am trying to set up a formula that changes the outcome based on the colors i selected.
i can't link the original sheet but i tried to put together a small test sheet to make it more clear

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/114DxB1vqdH9MHuE5jr-iR1WfUdjMk4sY0dtvkCN80Y8/edit?usp=sharing

The linked sheet discribes what i want to get.

- i tried allot of formulas and the closest i got gave me only the first result and it was combination of filter and vlookup but i accidently deleted that and can't really reproduce it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added formula to your sheet. Please test it out:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(LAMBDA(ax,{PROPER(INDEX(ax,,1)),IFERROR(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(INDEX(ax,,2),A:A&""&B:B,1,),""))})(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(D3:D&"|"&E3:E&""&TRANSPOSE(G3:G10)),"|",0,0),"Select * Where Col1!=''")),"Select * Where Col2!=''"))`

-

[image]

Comment: Can't believe how fast you did this.  I'll try it out In my other sheet!

Comment: This worked extremely well!

I was banging my head on this for days.... THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Another option it stacks up different queries with REDUCE, also gives you a message if product is not found in that colour:

```
=REDUCE({A2:B2,"colour"},SEQUENCE(COUNTA(E3:E)),LAMBDA(a,v,{a; IFERROR (QUERY(A3:B100,"SELECT '"&INDEX(D3:D,v)&"',A,B where A = '"&INDEX(E3:E,v)&"' and B matches '"&JOIN("|",FILTER(G3:G,G3:G<>""))&"' label '"&INDEX(D3:D,v)&"' ''",),{INDEX(D3:D,v),INDEX(E3:E,v),"not found in any colour"})}))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({VLOOKUP(A3:A10, {E3:E10, D3:D10}, 2, ), A3:B10}, 
 "where Col3 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, G3:G10)&"'", ))
```

[image]